# onReceive not work for incoming SMS

Tags: android, sms

I have a problem to catch new SMS message arrived in device

make a separate class for BroadcastReceiver

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

and in manifest

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.masoud.smsrecnonotif.SmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

and do not add any code at Main class

the problem is I receive SMS but there is no Log or toast.
need for any intent in main?thanks

Comment: If you are testing on KitKat or later, this may be of some help: http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: it should work on kitkat or any versions because of Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

Comment: Did you read the article? _"On Android 4.4, only *one* app can receive the new SMS_DELIVER_ACTION intent, which the system broadcasts when a new SMS message arrives."_ - The section of the manifest you provided does not currently conform to the requirements in order to be selected as a default SMS app.

Comment: yeah I read it before. I do not need to set my app as default thus to work with SMS_DELIVER_ACTION  similar to the other sms app installed in device this code should work with SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION just to read the sms

Comment: Ok, in which case you may just need to set the priority of the intent filter by replacing `<intent-filter>` with  `<intent-filter android:priority="1">` in your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark the onReceive method with @Override.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
}
```

Comment: I do it and the problem still exists.